# Pandas - Resort Column Location

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas frame. When I print the columns (shown below), its turns out that my columns are out of order. Is there a way to sort only the first 30 columns so they are in order (30,60,90...900)?

```
[in]   df.columns

[out]  Index(['120', '150', '180', '210', '240', '270', '30', '300', '330', '360',
   '390', '420', '450', '480', '510', '540', '570', '60', '600', '630',
   '660', '690', '720', '750', '780', '810', '840', '870', '90', '900',
   'Item', 'Price', 'Size', 'Time', 'Type', 'Unnamed: 0'],
  dtype='object')
```

The fixed frame would be as follows:

```
[out]  Index(['30','60','90,'120', '150', '180', '210', '240', '270','300', '330', '360',
   '390', '420', '450', '480', '510', '540', '570','600', '630',
   '660', '690', '720', '750', '780', '810', '840', '870','900',
   'Item', 'Price', 'Size', 'Time', 'Type', 'Unnamed: 0'],
  dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the columns will be named 30 through 900 in multiples of 30, you can generate that explicitly like this:

```
c = [str(i) for i in range(30, 901, 30)]
```

Then add it to the other columns:

```
c = c + ['Item', 'Price', 'Size', 'Time', 'Type', 'Unnamed: 0']
```

Then you should be able to access it as `df[c]`

Answer (score 0):

You need select first column names, convert to `int` and sort. Then convert back to `str` if necessary and use [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
np.sort(df.columns[:30].astype(int)).astype(str).tolist() +
             df.columns[30:].tolist()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(36).reshape(1,-1),
   columns=['120', '150', '180', '210', '240', '270', '30', '300', 
   '330', '360','390', '420', '450', '480', '510', '540', '570', '60', '600', '630',
   '660', '690', '720', '750', '780', '810', '840', '870', '90', '900',
   'Item', 'Price', 'Size', 'Time', 'Type', 'Unnamed: 0'])


print (df)
   120  150  180  210  240  270  30  300  330  360     ...      840  870  90  \
0    0    1    2    3    4    5   6    7    8    9     ...       26   27  28   

   900  Item  Price  Size  Time  Type  Unnamed: 0  
0   29    30     31    32    33    34          35  

[1 rows x 36 columns]


df = df.reindex_axis(np.sort(df.columns[:30].astype(int)).astype(str).tolist() + 
                     df.columns[30:].tolist(), axis=1)
print (df)
   30  60  90  120  150  180  210  240  270  300     ...      810  840  870  \
0   6  17  28    0    1    2    3    4    5    7     ...       25   26   27   

   900  Item  Price  Size  Time  Type  Unnamed: 0  
0   29    30     31    32    33    34          35  

[1 rows x 36 columns]
```